# Gaussian integral justification

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

So I read on the very nice proof of the Gaussian integral being equal to the root of pi and its application for the normal distribution (in fact the normal distribution is described by the Gaussian function). However, maybe the thoughts and proofs behind are really complex, but what decided that specifically the Gaussian function is able to describe the distribution of any Stochastic value repeated an infinite times? It can be seen in many places like physics, but what is the mathematical proof that this function described the probability distribution and not other functions with similar traits (like symmetry, converge to zero in infinity, etc.)?

Comment: You want the central limit theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Answer (score 2):

This is an extremely important result known as the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). [The proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Proof_of_classical_CLT) isn't terribly difficult either (at least considering how fundamental the theorem is).

Comment: A question about history: Gauss first proved the central limit theorem and then looked for the density that had such charachteristic function or were there some other twist in the story? :-)

Comment: @Ant I know very little about the history - perhaps if you are interested enough, you could ask on the [History of Science and Mathematics beta](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/) site :P

Comment: thanks for the reference! Maybe I will :)

Comment: "isn't terribly difficult" well this is what I call an understatement